# SQL Server intra-query parallel thread deadlock does not generate deadlock graph

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, database-deadlocks

I have a very odd problem... I am trying to solve some deadlock issues on a SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM production server.

I am using [trace flag 1222](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2130/finding-sql-server-deadlocks-using-trace-flag-1222/) ([and the good old 1204](http://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/Identify-Deadlocks-in-SQL-Server-Using-Trace-Flag-1222-and-1204/)) to get the details of queries and objects involved.

This has been working like a charm for most of the deadlocks until I stumbled into an intra-query parallel thread deadlock.

Trace flag 1204 does write the deadlock info to the Server Log file, but T1222 does not. I also tried to use the "Deadlock Graph" event in a Profiler trace with no luck, the deadlock is not detected either.

I therefore have no means to know which query triggers this annoying deadlock.

Do you have any idea on why the trace flag 1222 doesn't trace anything ? and how I can spot the faulty query ??

I have been searching answers on the web for days ... and couldn't find a post about a similar problem.

Many thanks for your advice !

Chris

EDIT : Here is the trace from 1204 trace flag :

```
Deadlock encountered .... Printing deadlock information
Wait-for graph
NULL
Node:1  
Port: 0x000000044E7E3980  Xid Slot: 31, Wait Slot: 13, Task: 0x0000000004380BC8, (Producer),     Exchange Wait Type: e_waitPipeNewRow, Merging: 1
 ResType:ExchangeId Stype:'AND' SPID:951 BatchID:0 ECID:51 TaskProxy:(0x00000001DB203220)     Value:0x4380bc8 Cost:(20/0)
   SPID: 951 ECID: 51 Statement Type: SELECT Line #: 123
   Input Buf: No Event: 
NULL
Node:2  
Port: 0x00000003F0D1D060  Xid Slot: 18, Wait Slot: 11, Task: 0x0000000004DBFB88, (Producer),     Exchange Wait Type: e_waitPipeNewRow, Merging: 1
 ResType:ExchangeId Stype:'AND' SPID:951 BatchID:0 ECID:2 TaskProxy:(0x000000023BF8DEE0)     Value:0x4dbfb88 Cost:(20/0)
NULL
Node:3  
Port: 0x000000043E40C500  Xid Slot: 13, Wait Slot: 18, Task: 0x0000000005037DC8, (Consumer),     Exchange Wait Type: e_waitPipeGetRow, Merging: 0
 ResType:ExchangeId Stype:'AND' SPID:951 BatchID:0 ECID:33 TaskProxy:(0x00000001DB202B60)     Value:0x5037dc8 Cost:(0/10000)
NULL
Node:4  
Port: 0x00000002DF5F7F20  Xid Slot: 11, Wait Slot: 31, Task: 0x00000001F80A02C8, (Consumer),     Exchange Wait Type: e_waitPipeGetRow, Merging: 0
 ResType:ExchangeId Stype:'AND' SPID:951 BatchID:0 ECID:37 TaskProxy:(0x00000001DB202CE0)    Value:0xf80a02c8 Cost:(0/10000)
```

Comment: Added some reference links. Could you in turn show how the relevant log entry looks like?

Comment: This looks relevant: [Today’s Annoyingly-Unwieldy Term: "Intra-Query Parallel Thread Deadlocks" - MSDN blogs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartd/2008/09/24/todays-annoyingly-unwieldy-term-intra-query-parallel-thread-deadlocks/).

Comment: And this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21767/why-are-there-victimless-entries-on-the-deadlock-graph

Comment: Thank you, indeed the root problem of the deadlock itself is related to the two articles you pointed to in your comments... I came across them both. To solve this deadlock, I need the detailed trace of flag 1222,  but for some reason it does not appear in the log, I only get the poor informational trace I added to my original post...